# Group Kendo ui chart category axis Date label rounding

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

On my below Kendo UI chart, I always wanted to show exactly 5 category (X) axis labels (which is achieved).

I have 2 questions (refer attached image for more details),

1) These labels have to be properly rounded in near by hour or 30 minute

2) Tooltip has to be formatted in **dd.MM.yy HH:tt**

Data for this chart is received dynamically. I cannot use the category axis type as 'Date' as I wanted to show all data points on the graph.

My sample code is available below,

```js
  
  var dataSource=[{"precisionIndex":0,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T13:16:29.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.7000000000,"data_4":-7.6000000000,"data_5":-3.0000000000},{"precisionIndex":800,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T13:16:29.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.7000000000,"data_4":-7.6000000000,"data_5":-3.0000000000},{"precisionIndex":1,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T13:24:50.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.8000000000,"data_4":-7.8000000000,"data_5":-2.9000000000},{"precisionIndex":3,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T13:36:00.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.8000000000,"data_4":-7.4000000000,"data_5":-2.8000000000},{"precisionIndex":4,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T13:41:34.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.9000000000,"data_4":-7.5000000000,"data_5":-3.0000000000},{"precisionIndex":5,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T13:47:09.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.7000000000,"data_4":-7.7000000000,"data_5":-3.1000000000},{"precisionIndex":6,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T13:52:44.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.6000000000,"data_4":-8.1000000000,"data_5":-3.1000000000},{"precisionIndex":7,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T13:58:18.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.6000000000,"data_4":-8.3000000000,"data_5":-3.3000000000},{"precisionIndex":8,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:03:53.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.6000000000,"data_4":-9.0000000000,"data_5":-3.3000000000},{"precisionIndex":9,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:09:28.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.8000000000,"data_4":-9.1000000000,"data_5":-3.5000000000},{"precisionIndex":10,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:15:02.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.8000000000,"data_4":-9.5000000000,"data_5":-3.8000000000},{"precisionIndex":11,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:20:37.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.6000000000,"data_4":-9.7000000000,"data_5":-3.7000000000},{"precisionIndex":12,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:26:12.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.7000000000,"data_4":-9.9000000000,"data_5":-3.8000000000},{"precisionIndex":13,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:31:46.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.6000000000,"data_4":-10.2000000000,"data_5":-3.9000000000},{"precisionIndex":14,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:37:21.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.5000000000,"data_4":-10.6000000000,"data_5":-4.3000000000},{"precisionIndex":15,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:42:56.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.7000000000,"data_4":-11.0000000000,"data_5":-4.5000000000},{"precisionIndex":16,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:48:30.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.7000000000,"data_4":-11.4000000000,"data_5":-4.3000000000},{"precisionIndex":17,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:54:05.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.5000000000,"data_4":-11.8000000000,"data_5":-4.8000000000},{"precisionIndex":18,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T14:59:40.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.7000000000,"data_4":-12.1000000000,"data_5":-5.1000000000},{"precisionIndex":24,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T15:33:07.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.7000000000,"data_4":-12.3000000000,"data_5":-5.5000000000},{"precisionIndex":26,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T15:44:17.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.7000000000,"data_4":-12.2000000000,"data_5":-5.7000000000},{"precisionIndex":27,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T15:49:51.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.6000000000,"data_4":-12.3000000000,"data_5":-5.7000000000},{"precisionIndex":28,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T15:55:26.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.7000000000,"data_4":-12.4000000000,"data_5":-5.8000000000},{"precisionIndex":29,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:01:01.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.5000000000,"data_4":-13.1000000000,"data_5":-5.9000000000},{"precisionIndex":30,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:06:35.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.5000000000,"data_4":-13.4000000000,"data_5":-6.3000000000},{"precisionIndex":31,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:12:10.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-21.9000000000,"data_4":-13.6000000000,"data_5":-6.7000000000},{"precisionIndex":32,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:17:45.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.0000000000,"data_4":-13.9000000000,"data_5":-6.9000000000},{"precisionIndex":33,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:23:19.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.1000000000,"data_4":-13.7000000000,"data_5":-7.4000000000},{"precisionIndex":34,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:28:54.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.1000000000,"data_4":-14.3000000000,"data_5":-7.9000000000},{"precisionIndex":35,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:34:29.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.3000000000,"data_4":-14.3000000000,"data_5":-8.0000000000},{"precisionIndex":36,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:40:03.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.3000000000,"data_4":-14.4000000000,"data_5":-8.4000000000},{"precisionIndex":37,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:45:38.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.4000000000,"data_4":-14.8000000000,"data_5":-8.4000000000},{"precisionIndex":38,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:51:13.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.4000000000,"data_4":-15.0000000000,"data_5":-9.0000000000},{"precisionIndex":39,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T16:56:47.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.2000000000,"data_4":-15.2000000000,"data_5":-9.3000000000},{"precisionIndex":40,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T17:02:22.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.4000000000,"data_4":-15.6000000000,"data_5":-9.6000000000},{"precisionIndex":41,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T17:07:57.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.5000000000,"data_4":-15.7000000000,"data_5":-10.0000000000},{"precisionIndex":42,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T17:13:31.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.6000000000,"data_4":-16.1000000000,"data_5":-10.6000000000},{"precisionIndex":43,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T17:19:06.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.5000000000,"data_4":-16.6000000000,"data_5":-11.5000000000},{"precisionIndex":44,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T17:24:40.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.8000000000,"data_4":-16.6000000000,"data_5":-11.7000000000},{"precisionIndex":45,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T17:30:15.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.7000000000,"data_4":-16.7000000000,"data_5":-11.8000000000},{"precisionIndex":46,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T17:35:50.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.7000000000,"data_4":-16.4000000000,"data_5":-12.0000000000},{"precisionIndex":47,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T17:41:24.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.7000000000,"data_4":-17.2000000000,"data_5":-12.5000000000},{"precisionIndex":48,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T17:46:59.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.9000000000,"data_4":-17.3000000000,"data_5":-12.6000000000},{"precisionIndex":50,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T17:58:08.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.8000000000,"data_4":-17.4000000000,"data_5":-13.0000000000},{"precisionIndex":52,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T18:09:18.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.7000000000,"data_4":-17.4000000000,"data_5":-12.9000000000},{"precisionIndex":53,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T18:14:52.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.7000000000,"data_4":-17.4000000000,"data_5":-13.0000000000},{"precisionIndex":55,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T18:26:02.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.7000000000,"data_4":-17.7000000000,"data_5":-13.1000000000},{"precisionIndex":57,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T18:37:11.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.8000000000,"data_4":-17.5000000000,"data_5":-13.1000000000},{"precisionIndex":59,"subPrecisionIndex":0,"measurementDate":"2017-06-07T18:48:20.4","data_1":22.0000000000,"data_2":-22.0000000000,"data_3":-22.7000000000,"data_4":-17.6000000000,"data_5":-13.0000000000}];
  
  $("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    seriesDefaults: {
      type: "line"
    },
    series: [
      {
        field: "data_3",
        name: "Profit 2"
      },
      {
        field: "data_4",
        name: "Profit 1"
      }],
    categoryAxis: {
      field: "measurementDate",
      type:"category",
      labels: {
        template: function(e){
          var val =new Date(e.value);
          var label = kendo.toString(val, "dd.MM.yy HH:mm");
          return label.split(" ").join("\n");
        }
      }
    },
    valueAxis: {
      axisCrossingValue: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
    },
    tooltip: {
      visible: true,
      shared: true
    },
    dataBound: function (e) {
      var ds = this.dataSource.data();
      var maxDateCategories = 4;
      var step = Math.round(ds.length / maxDateCategories);
      // display only 'n'th categories on xAxis
      this.options.categoryAxis.labels.step = step;
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Tooltip you can use the **[sharedTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-tooltip.sharedTemplate)** to format the category as desired:

```
sharedTemplate: '<div> #= kendo.toString(new Date(category), "dd.MM.yy HH:mm") # </div># for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) { # <div>#: points[i].series.name# : #: points[i].value #</div># } #'
```

For the label template, add your own rounding logic for the timestamp, e.g.:

```
  labels: {
    template: function(e){
      var val =new Date(e.value);
      var mins = val.getMinutes();
      if (mins < 15 ) {
        val.setMinutes(0);
      } else if (mins < 45) {
        val.setMinutes(30);
      } else {
        val.setHours(val.getHours() + 1);
        val.setMinutes(0);
      }
      var label = kendo.toString(val, "dd.MM.yy HH:mm");
      return label.split(" ").join("\n");
    }
  }
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/eqoDET)**

Comment: Thank you @ezanker.

Comment: By the way do you know any other better way to show four X axis labels without using **step** ?